# Multiplying Calculator Function in Python

Tags: python

I wrote the code below with **"return"**, but it doesn't work. What do I need to change in my code (return line) to get the correct result?

```
def multiply():
    integer_1 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    integer_2 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    answer = integer_1 * integer_2
    return(str(integer_1), "*", str(integer_2), "=", answer)

multiply()
```

**My output:**

```
('9', '*', '13', '=', 117)
```

**Desired output:**

```
9 * 13 = 117
```

Comment: return isint a function

Comment: You're looking for [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: `return str(integer_1) + "*" + str(integer_2) + "=" + answer)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return isn't a function. Also the use of joining the items of the list helps.

```
def multiply():
    integer_1 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    integer_2 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    answer = integer_1 * integer_2
    return ' '.join((str(integer_1), "*", str(integer_2), "=", str(answer)))

print(multiply()) #print() is used to print the data without '
```

or just:

```
return str(integer_1) + " * " + str(integer_2) + " = " + str(answer)
```

Comment: That `return` isn't a function doesn't matter at all here because this syntax won't be parsed as a function call.

Comment: @ForceBru The author used `return()` just like calling a function, that's why we're telling them return is not a function.

Comment: `' '.join(str(integer_1) "*", str(integer_2), "=", answer)` is a `TypeError` because `str.join` accepts one argument, not 5. Also, `answer` is an integer, so it can't be concatenated with a string

Comment: Both doesn't work.. I get the following error for the one with join:   File "<ipython-input-19-e3777c74cc85>", line 6
    return ' '.join((str(integer_1) "*", str(integer_2), "=", answer))
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .

For the second one:

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 1):

Return is not a function, so the correct syntax should be:

```
return str(integer_1)+" * "+str(integer_2)+" = "+str(answer)
```

Where `+` means to combine two strings together.

Comment: `return(a, b)` is correct syntax. It will simply return a tuple.

Comment: @ForceBru I mean the correct syntax for combining string. I know it could return a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use f-strings for this:

```
return(f'{integer_1} * {integer_2} = {answer}')
```

This allows you to create your output statement without any string concatenation.

And since you are returning a value, you must assign the output of `multiply()` to a variable. For example:

```
output = multiply()
```

So in full:

```
def multiply():
    integer_1 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    integer_2 = int(input("enter a whole number: "))
    answer = integer_1 * integer_2
    return(f'{integer_1} * {integer_2} = {answer}')

output = multiply()
print(output)
```

See this article about [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) from realpython.com